# Disable Remote Desktop Client Keyboard Shortcut

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, resharper, remote-desktop

I use Remote Desktop occasionally for some programming tasks but the <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Insert</kbd> keyboard shortcut (cycle through windows) in the client intercepts the default ReSharper generate code shortcut.

Does anyone know if it's possible to remap (or disable) that Remote Desktop keyboard shortcut? I would prefer not to have to remap the ReSharper shortcut if possible.

Answer (score 7):

Figured it out. This problem was when I was not running in full screen mode.

In the Remote Desktop Connection dialog, 
Local Resources -> Keyboard = On the remote computer

Now I can use <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Insert</kbd> along with all the other shortcut keys when the Remote Desktop client window is in focus.

Answer (score 0):

I thought it was still intercepting ALT+Page Down and ALT+Page Up.

It turns out it was Skype.